# django rest framework не позволят отправить post

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос такого плана: почему django rest framework не позволят отправить post для отдельных View

Есть код, который позволяет проверить токен:

```
# path('auth/', views.AuthView.as_view()),
class AuthView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser]

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={
            '200': 'Успешно',
            '401': 'Нет токена',
            '403': 'Неуспешная авторизация'
        },
    )
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'ok',
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Он спокойно обрабатывает POST(в заголовке: `'Allow': 'POST, OPTIONS'`), но если я беру другой view

```
# path('info/create/', views.CreateInfoView.as_view()),
class CreateInfoView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated]

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={
            '201': 'Информация успешно создана',
            '400': 'Некорректные данные',
            '401': 'Нет токена',
            '403': 'Неуспешная авторизация'
        },
    )
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'ok',
        }
        return Response(content)
```

То здесь я получаю ошибку `{"detail":"Method \\"POST\\" not allowed."}`, а в headers: `'Allow': 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS'`.
С чем это связанно и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была с ссылками в urls.py
Было:

```
    path('info/', views.GetInfosView.as_view()),
    path('info/<skin_id>/', views.GetInfoView.as_view()),
    path('info/create/', views.CreateInfoView.as_view()),
    path('info/<skin_id>/delete/', views.DeleteInfoView.as_view()),
    path('info/<skin_id>/patch/', views.PatchInfoView.as_view()),
```

Стало:

```
    path('info/', views.GetInfosView.as_view()),
    path('info/create/', views.CreateInfoView.as_view()),
    path('info/<skin_id>/', views.GetInfoView.as_view()),
    path('info/<skin_id>/delete/', views.DeleteInfoView.as_view()),
    path('info/<skin_id>/patch/', views.PatchInfoView.as_view()),
```